# C++ Create a cube with sections

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to create a cube/box where each dimension can be divided into sections. Something similar to rings and sides when creating a sphere or a cylinder.

For example to get all the vertices for a sphere at once one can do:

```
for (int r = 0; r < rings-1; ++r)
{
    float u = -M_PI_2 + ((r+1) * M_PI / rings);
    float v = -M_PI;

    for (int s= 0; s < sides; ++s)
    {
        float x = radius * cos(u) * cos(v);
        float y = radius * sin(u);
        float z = radius * cos(u) * sin(v);
        add_vertex(x, y, z);
        v += 2 * M_PI / sides;
    }
}
```

Any help on how to go about doing something like that in theory would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code wich create cude with stacks, wslices and dslices. It was used to draw array buffers to OpenGL. You can simply remove unused normal and color array and use only vertex array. And do not be affraid because of `GLint` and `GLfloat` types they are only int and float synonyms.

```
void DrawBox(GLfloat fWidth,GLfloat fHeight,GLfloat fDepth,GLint wslices,GLint dslices,GLint stacks)
{
     // Calculate number of primitives on each side of box
     // because we can use different tessalation configurations 
     // we must calculate separate group of box sides 

    int iTopButtonQuads = wslices * dslices * 2; // Calculate number of quads in top and button sides
    int iLeftRightQuads = dslices * stacks * 2; // Calculate number of quads in left and right sides
    int iFrontBackQuads = wslices * stacks * 2; // Calculate number of quads in front and back sides

    // If we consider to use quads as primitive then each primitive will
    // have 4 points, and each point has color, coord and normal attribute.
    // So we create separate array to contain each attibute values.

    float* pfVertices = new float[(iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 3 * 4];
    float* pfColors = new float[(iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 3 * 4];
    float* pfNormals = new float[(iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 3 * 4];

    int iVertexIndex = 0;

    GLfloat Xstep = fWidth / wslices;
    GLfloat Ystep = fHeight / stacks;
    GLfloat Zstep = fDepth / dslices;

    GLfloat firstX = fWidth / 2.0f;
    GLfloat firstY = fHeight / 2.0f;
    GLfloat firstZ = fDepth / 2.0f;

    GLfloat currX = 0.0f;
    GLfloat currY = 0.0f;
    GLfloat currZ = 0.0f;

    GLfloat x_status = 0.0f;
    GLfloat y_status = 0.0f;
    GLfloat z_status = 0.0f;

    // the bottom and the top of the box
    for (currZ = -firstZ, z_status = 0.0f; currZ < firstZ - Zstep / 2.0f; currZ += Zstep, z_status += Zstep)
    {
        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX,-firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,-firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX + Xstep,-firstY,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,-firstY,currZ + Zstep};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }

        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX + Xstep,firstY,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX,firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,firstY,currZ + Zstep};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }
    }

    // the front and the back of the box
    for (currY = -firstY, y_status = 0.0f; currY < firstY - Ystep / 2.0f ; currY += Ystep, y_status += Ystep)
    {
        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX,currY,firstZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY,firstZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY + Ystep,firstZ};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,currY + Ystep,firstZ};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }

        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY + Ystep,-firstZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY,-firstZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX,currY,-firstZ};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,currY + Ystep,-firstZ};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }
    }

    // Right side and the left side of the box
    for (currY = -firstY, y_status = 0.0f; currY < firstY - Ystep / 2.0f; currY += Ystep, y_status += Ystep)
    {
        for (currZ = -firstZ, z_status = 0.0f; currZ < firstZ - Zstep / 2.0f; currZ += Zstep, z_status += Zstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {firstX,currY,currZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {firstX,currY,currZ + Zstep};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }

        for (currZ = -firstZ, z_status = 0.0f; currZ < firstZ - Zstep / 2.0f; currZ += Zstep, z_status += Zstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {-firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {-firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)pfColors);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)pfNormals);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)pfVertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, (iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    delete [] pfVertices;
    delete [] pfNormals;
    delete [] pfColors;
}
```

here is the code to optimize vertex arrays.

```
// 1254 Verticies
// 2141 Texture Coordinates
// 1227 Normals
// 2248 Triangles

static short face_indicies[2248][9] = {
// Object #-1
    {0,15,14 ,0,1,2 ,0,1,2 }, {0,1,15 ,0,3,1 ,0,3,1 }, {1,16,15 ,3,4,1 ,3,4,1 },
    {1,2,16 ,3,5,4 ,3,5,4 }, {2,17,16 ,5,6,4 ,5,6,4 }, {2,3,17 ,5,7,6 ,5,7,6 },
    {3,18,17 ,7,8,6 ,7,8,6 }, {3,4,18 ,7,9,8 ,7,9,8 }, {4,19,18 ,9,10,8 ,9,10,8 },
    //.................................................................
};

static GLfloat vertices [1254][3] = {
{1.32715f,-1.99755f,-0.614826f},{1.32715f,-2.20819f,-0.343913f},{1.32715f,-2.5155f,-0.191263f},
{1.32715f,-2.85867f,-0.187049f},{1.32715f,-3.16964f,-0.332104f},{1.32715f,-3.38686f,-0.597763f},
{1.32715f,-3.46734f,-0.931359f},{1.32715f,-3.39508f,-1.26683f},{1.32715f,-3.18445f,-1.53774f},
    //..................................................................
};

static GLfloat normals [1227][3] = {
{-0.45634f,0.376195f,-0.80637f},{0.456348f,0.688811f,-0.563281f},{0.45634f,0.376194f,-0.80637f},
{-0.456348f,0.688811f,-0.563281f},{0.456341f,0.865005f,-0.208615f},{-0.456341f,0.865005f,-0.208615f},
{0.456341f,0.869868f,0.187303f},{-0.456341f,0.869868f,0.187303f},{0.456349f,0.702436f,0.546196f},
    //..................................................................
};

static GLfloat textures [2141][2] = {
{0.94929f,0.497934f},{0.99452f,0.477509f},{0.994669f,0.497506f},
{0.949142f,0.47796f},{0.994339f,0.457508f},{0.948961f,0.457992f},
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// These are hard coded for this particular example
GLushort uiIndexes[2248*3];   // Maximum number of indexes
GLfloat vVerts[2248*3][3];  // (Worst case scenario)
GLfloat vText[2248*3][2];
GLfloat vNorms[2248*3][3];
int iLastIndex = 0;         // Number of indexes actually used



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compare two floating point values and return true if they are
// close enough together to be considered the same.
int IsSame(float x, float y, float epsilon)
    {
    if(fabs(x-y) < epsilon)
        return 1;

    return 0;
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Goes through the arrays and looks for duplicate verticies 
// that can be shared. This expands the original array somewhat
// and returns the number of true unique verticies that now
// populates the vVerts array.
int IndexTriangles(void)
    {
    int iFace, iPoint, iMatch;
    float e = 0.000001; // How small a difference to equate

    // LOOP THROUGH all the faces
    int iIndexCount = 0;
    for(iFace = 0; iFace < 2248; iFace++)
        {
        for(iPoint = 0; iPoint < 3; iPoint++)
            {
            // Search for match
            for(iMatch = 0; iMatch < iLastIndex; iMatch++)
                {
                // If Vertex is the same...
                if(IsSame(vertices[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint]][0], vVerts[iMatch][0], e) &&
                   IsSame(vertices[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint]][1], vVerts[iMatch][1], e) &&
                   IsSame(vertices[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint]][2], vVerts[iMatch][2], e) &&

                   // AND the Normal is the same...
                   IsSame(normals[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+3]][0], vNorms[iMatch][0], e) &&
                   IsSame(normals[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+3]][1], vNorms[iMatch][1], e) &&
                   IsSame(normals[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+3]][2], vNorms[iMatch][2], e) &&

                   // And Texture is the same...
                   IsSame(textures[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+6]][0], vText[iMatch][0], e) &&
                   IsSame(textures[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+6]][1], vText[iMatch][1], e))
                    {
                    // Then add the index only
                    uiIndexes[iIndexCount] = iMatch;
                    iIndexCount++;
                    break;
                    }
                }

            // No match found, add this vertex to the end of our list, and update the index array
            if(iMatch == iLastIndex)
                {
                // Add data and new index
                memcpy(vVerts[iMatch], vertices[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint]], sizeof(float) * 3);
                memcpy(vNorms[iMatch], normals[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+3]], sizeof(float) * 3);
                memcpy(vText[iMatch],  textures[face_indicies[iFace][iPoint+6]], sizeof(float) * 2);
                uiIndexes[iIndexCount] = iLastIndex;
                iIndexCount++;
                iLastIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    return iIndexCount;
     }

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to stitch the triangles together
// and draw the ship
void DrawModel(void)
    {
    static int iIndexes = 0;
    char cBuffer[32];


    // The first time this is called, reindex the triangles. Report the results
    // in the window title
    if(iIndexes == 0)
        {
        iIndexes = IndexTriangles();
        sprintf(cBuffer,"Verts = %d Indexes = %d", iLastIndex, iIndexes);
        glutSetWindowTitle(cBuffer); 
        }

    // Use vertices, normals, and texture coordinates
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Here's where the data is now
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,0, vVerts);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, vNorms);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vText);

    // Draw them
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, iIndexes, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, uiIndexes);
    }
```

This algo will works with arbitrary mesh array. **Or just place unique values it means remove the values where `curr + step` occurs so must be left 1 vertex per loop body not all 4.** Example

Where we have 4 vertices

```
  float pfVertex0[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ};
  float pfVertex1[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ + Zstep};
  float pfVertex2[3] = {-firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ + Zstep};
  float pfVertex3[3] = {-firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ};
```

The only vertex left will be

```
  float pfVertex0[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ};
```

The simple arithmetic shows 24 / 4 = 6 != 8
so to form proper box we just must add extra iteration to 1 side of the box (2 vertices).

Comment: I was trying to avoid having separate loops for each face (not sure if its possible) but this is a very acceptable answer, I look into it and mark it as an answer appropriately. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @J. Doe: You can group the loops where is identical tabulation values. currX, currY, currZ

Comment: There is one issue with the above. It doesn’t create unique vertices. For example: for a simple cube instead of 8 vertices you would have 24. This is perfect when you are using it just for rendering.

Comment: @J. Doe: Not a problem. Wait a minute I will post optimization code.

Comment: I don't think looping through the existing elements to find duplicates would be a favorable solution. For example if you see the **ofMesh::box()** function in the following link it creates unique vertices without that extra trouble. The only problem is that it creates triangles, I would prefer quads.

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/3d/ofMesh.cpp

Comment: @J. Doe: I have updated my ansver. The only problem is to add extra iteration where vertices was excluded. I thing you can figure out how to do this from actual result.

Comment: There is no need to loop through the arrays for duplicates when you can create unique vertices on the fly. Imagine if you had a box with 128 sections on each side, thats over 2 million vertices. If you were to search for duplicates every vertex (set aside normals and UV's) would take a very very long time.

Comment: @J. Doe: Read the end of the post carefully. I mark my new answer as bold. There are no need for full mesh optimization.